# React Native Typescript : how to resolve an error of type of parameter for a variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, state

I'm doing a project in react native (typescript) and here is my issue : I have this error `Argument of type 'GestureResponderEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.ts(2345)` with this part of my code, at the i of setSelected :

```
<View style={{}}>
          <Text style={styles.texteti}>Heading, paragraphe, lien</Text>
          {state.map((i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(i) => setSelected(i)}> 
              <Text>{i} Here</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
          {selected == "v1Visible" && (
            <View>
              <Text>View 1</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          {selected == "v2Visible" && (
            <View>
              <Text>View 2</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          {selected == "v3Visible" && (
            <View>
              <Text>View 3</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          {selected == "v4Visible" && (
            <View>
              <Text>View 4</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
```

Anyone has an idea of how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the variable with name `i` in the callback function passed to `onPress` of the `TouchableOpacity`. You are using the same variable name in your `map` function of `state`. Since the setter `setSelected` is called in the local scope of the callback function of `onPress`, the event passed to this callback function will be used (it is stored in `i` of the local scope of the callback function).

The easiest fix would be to either rename the variable or not declare it at all since you are not using it anyway.

```js
{state.map((i) => (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelected(i)}> 
          <Text>{i} Here</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

If you actually want to store the event of the `onPress` action (which seems to be unlikely judging from your current code), you need to either change the typing of your state or access whatever you want to access from the event.